# Parallelize transitive reduction

Tags: c#, algorithm, parallel-processing

I have a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`, where the Key represents an element of a set (or a vertex in an oriented graph) and the List is a set of other elements which are in relation with the Key (so there are oriented edges from Key to Values). The dictionary is optimized for creating a Hasse diagram, so the Values are always smaller than the Key.

I have also a simple sequential algorithm, that removes all transitive edges (e.g. I have relations 1->2, 2->3 and 1->3. I can remove the edge 1->3, because I have a path between 1 and 3 via 2).

```
for(int i = 1; i < dictionary.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if(dictionary[i].Contains(j))
                dictionary[i].RemoveAll(r => dictionary[j].Contains(r));
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to parallelize the algorithm? I could do Parallel.For for the inner loop. However, this is not recommended (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) and the resulting speed would not increase significantly (+ there might be problems with locking). Could I parallelize the outer loop?

Comment: Search Stackoverflow for "thread safe dictionary"

Comment: Is the graph a transitive closure? Otherwise this would not work (think about 1->2, 2->3, 3->4, 1->4).

Comment: Yes, it is. If it was not, a Hasse diagram could not be formed.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way to solve the parallelization problem, separate data. Read from original data structure and write to new. That way You can run it in parallel without even need to lock.

But probably the parallelization is not even necessary, the data structures are not efficient. You use dictionary where array would be sufficient (as I understand the code You have vertices `0..result.Count-1`). And `List<int>` for lookups. `List.Contains` is very inefficient. `HashSet` would be better. Or, for more dense graphs, `BitArray`. So instead of `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` You can use `BitArray[]`.

I rewrote the algorithm and made some optimizations. It does not make plain copy of the graph and delete edges, it just construct the new graph from only the right edges. It uses `BitArray[]` for input graph and `List<int>[]` for final graph, as the latter one is far more sparse.

```
int sizeOfGraph = 1000;

//create vertices of a graph
BitArray[] inputGraph = new BitArray[sizeOfGraph];
for (int i = 0; i < inputGraph.Length; ++i)
{
    inputGraph[i] = new BitArray(i);
}

//fill random edges
Random rand = new Random(10);
for (int i = 1; i < inputGraph.Length; ++i)
{
    BitArray vertex_i = inputGraph[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < vertex_i.Count; ++j)
    {
        if(rand.Next(0, 100) < 50) //50% fill ratio
        {
            vertex_i[j] = true;
        }
    }
}

//create transitive closure
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfGraph; ++i)
{
    BitArray vertex_i = inputGraph[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        if (vertex_i[j]) { continue; }
        for (int r = j + 1; r < i; ++r)
        {
            if (vertex_i[r] && inputGraph[r][j])
            {
                vertex_i[j] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

//create transitive reduction
List<int>[] reducedGraph = new List<int>[sizeOfGraph];
Parallel.ForEach(inputGraph, (vertex_i, state, ii) =>
{
    {
        int i = (int)ii;
        List<int> reducedVertex = reducedGraph[i] = new List<int>();

        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j)
        {
            if (vertex_i[j])
            {
                bool ok = true;
                for (int x = 0; x < reducedVertex.Count; ++x)
                {
                    if (inputGraph[reducedVertex[x]][j])
                    {
                        ok = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (ok)
                {
                    reducedVertex.Add(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

MessageBox.Show("Finished, reduced graph has "
    + reducedGraph.Sum(s => s.Count()) + " edges.");
```

**EDIT**

I wrote this:
<s>The code has some problems. With the direction `i` goes now, You can delete edges You would need and the result would be incorrect.</s> This turned out to be a mistake. I was thinking this way, lets have a graph

```
1->0
2->1, 2->0
3->2, 3->1, 3->0
```

Vertex 2 gets reduced by vertex 1, so we have

```
1->0
2->1
3->2, 3->1, 3->0
```

Now vertex 3 gets reduced by vertex 2

```
1->0
2->1
3->2, 3->0
```

And we have a problem, as we can not reduce `3->0` which stayed here because of reduced `2->0`. But it is my mistake, this would never happen. The inner cycle goes strictly from lower to higher, so instead

Vertex 3 gets reduced by vertex 1

```
1->0
2->1
3->2, 3->1
```

and now by vertex 2

```
1->0
2->1
3->2
```

And the result is correct. I apologize for the error.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your algorithm. Could you, please, elaborate, why is there a problem with the i incrementation? I am sure, there are no relations, where j>=i, so the binary matrix of relations has true values only under the i-j diagonal (lower triangle).